# Classic ASP Array not returning values, error 500

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I'm working on executing the same code several times to produce a table. My first thoughts went out to using an array to do this.

Here is what i have got so far:

```
Dim iRow
iRow = 0 

'alternate color for rows   
Do While Not rsGlobalWeb.EOF 
If iRow Mod 2 = 0 Then 
    response.write "<tr bgcolor=""#FFFFFF"">"
Else 
    response.write "<tr bgcolor=""#EEEEEE"">"
End If 

'some other code
SqlBackup = "SELECT * FROM CMDBbackup WHERE Naam_Cattools = '" & rsGlobalWeb("Device_name") & "'" 
Set rsBackup = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsBackup.Open SqlBackup, dbGlobalWeb, 3     

'declaration of array
Dim fieldname(5),i
fieldname(0) = "Device_name"
fieldname(1) = "Image"
fieldname(2) = "Backup"
fieldname(3) = "Uptime"
fieldname(4) = "Processor"
fieldname(5) = "Nvram"

For i = 0 to 5
    If rsGlobalWeb(fieldname(i)) <> "" Then
        response.write("<td>" & rsGlobalWeb(fieldname(i)) & "</td>")
    Else
        If Not rsBackup.EOF Then
            If Not IsNull(rsBackup(fieldname(i))) And (rsBackup(fieldname(i)) <> "") Then
                response.write("<td>" & rsBackup(fieldname(i)) & " (backup)</td>")
            End if
        Else
            response.write("<td>No data found</td>")
        End if
    End if  
Next

response.write("</tr>")

iRow = iRow + 1
rsGlobalWeb.MoveNext 
Loop
```

The issue i have now is that the following error occurs even tho i have friendly messages turned off:

"500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

The logfile shows the following:
"DaEngineSDB.asp |58|800a000d|Type_mismatch 80 -" Where the 58 is the line with the Dim Fieldname.

Without the array it does show the remainder of the code (i have 1 other field which gets added). If i remove the array and fill the fieldname(i) with a normal string value it also works fine.

I was trying out stuff that google says but after attempting several things i am still running up to a wall.
Any ideas what it could be?

Thanks in advance,

Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved!

After banging my head against the wall for a day i found out that i stupidly declared the array inside the DO WHILE loop. Moved the declaration out of it and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

First you should turn on error displaying in your iis, or read the error log for its description, google it if not sure how.

Without error description, it's way too difficult to check what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i've checked the log file and it shows: DaEngineSDB.asp |58|800a000d|Type_mismatch. In the full code on line 58 is the line with Dim fieldname.